# How to style strings where they are like the term of search

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Flutter, I have made a small script for search notes. It work fine but I'd like to know how to make a color style for strings where they are like the term of search.

For example if I write **"is"** in the search field, so all strings **"is"** in all the texts in result should be in **different color and bold**.

[image]

This is some of the script:

```
  // the controller of FieldText is _qController: 
  // final _qController = TextEditingController(); 

  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: dbmanager.search(_qController.text),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        noteList = snapshot.data;
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: noteList == null ? 0 : noteList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
              note = noteList[index];
              String title = note.title;
              String description = note.description;
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 1.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                child: Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ViewNote(
                            note: noteList[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    title: Text(title.isNotEmpty ? title : 'Aucun titre'),
                    subtitle: Text(description.length < 100
                        ? description
                        : description.substring(1, 100)),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `Text` widget you can take a look at [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) which would allow you to achieve such thing. You could have a function that takes in your search string and the string that you want to display and then return based on that a `RichText` widget that has the search term string highlighted.

What the following code does is that it builds the phrase "hello this is working as intended" and highlights in bold all the words that are found in the `TextField`, this is a small example of the kind of logic you can do to build your text.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String searched = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            onChanged: (String word) {
              setState(() {
                searched = word;
              });
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 100),
          buildRichText("hello this is working as intended", searched),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  checkWordContained(String word, String searched){
    for(String searchWord in searched.split(" ")){
      if(word == searchWord){
        return FontWeight.bold;
      }
    }
    return FontWeight.normal;
  }

  Widget buildRichText(String phrase, String searched) {
    List<InlineSpan> children = [];
    for (String word in phrase.split(" ")) {
      children.add(
        TextSpan(
          text: "$word ",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: checkWordContained(word,searched)),
        ),
      );
    }
    return RichText(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      text: TextSpan(
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
        children: children,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm beginner of flutter (few days ago), no problem using RichText, but it's hard for me to find that function which do styling strings

Comment: Inside of RichText you can do the styling, for example one of the children of the richtext could be ```TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),``` which would display the word "bold" in bold

Comment: I have seen RichText and I have included it in the code, I think the problem now is how to   cut the text result into 2 or 3 pieces and put each one in a TextSpan

Comment: @hous I've attached a small code example, it's not perfect but it's the best I could do in a short time. Please take a look

Comment: Ok I'll test it and then accept your answer , thank you so much

Comment: Gladly! Please let me know should you need any other help

Comment: your code works perfect , but i search by word. I mean the string will be bold unless the complete word is like the term of search. For example if a phrase "This is the first note" , and I search for string "fir" , the word first in the phrase would not be in bold, I should write all the world "first" in the search field, do you understand me ?

Comment: Yes I do, to do that you'd have to just find a different algorithm to build the richText but the general idea hold true, as far as I'm aware the only way to style your text as is would be by dynamically building a rich text, which I believe is what you wanted. I wish I could help build the algorithm but I currently can't